# Jenkins won't start. Error: jenkins class hudson.security.csrf.defaultcrumbissuer is missing its descriptor

Tags: java, jenkins

I have been running Jenkins for 10 years, but after I upgraded Jenkins.war ( 2.361.4 LTS by 2022-11-17) to the latest version, and also openjdk-17-jre on Ubuntu Focal 20.04 LTS. Jenkins keeps restarting and throws the following stack trace to to the log (long version omited):

`java.lang.AssertionError: class hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer is missing its descriptor`

How to fix the problem?

```
I'm starting jenkins by command:

    jenkins -jar jenkins.war
```

I'd expect Jenkins to start. Jenkins gives "Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work ..." on the web page, but then restarts and never actually starts.

After a while I also got an error message (both on web and log):

WARNING o.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser#parseFields: Header is too large 8193>8192

After waiting for a while there comes also message on the log:

```
Jenkins initial setup is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the missing descriptor seems to be just warning, and is not a fatal error. Just wait until you get more output to the log
2. Jenkins initial setup -error message shows because I was starting Jenkins by hand, and not by the Ubuntu startup script, and was doing so as root. Starting the command by

   sudo -u jenkins java -jar jenkins.war

restored the previous environment.